# Load data from .csv applying regex before insert into table

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, shell, csv

I know that there is a code to import .csv data into a mysql table, and I'm using this one:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "file.csv" INTO TABLE foo FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\\r\\n";
```

The data inside this .csv are lines like this example:

```
08/e0/Breast_Cancer_Res_2001_Nov_2_3(1)_55-60.tar.gz Breast Cancer Res. 2001 Nov 2; 3(1):55-60 PMC13900
b0/ac/Breast_Cancer_Res_2001_Nov_9_3(1)_61-65.tar.gz Breast Cancer Res. 2001 Nov 9; 3(1):61-65 PMC13901
```

I just want the first part (the .tar.gz path), always on the pattern

```
(letter or number)(letter or number) / (letter or number)(letter or number)/...
```

and the part starting by 'PMC', always on the pattern

```
PMC(number...)
```

where 'number' means a number between 0 to 9
and a letter means a letter between a to z (both upper and lower case)

So, applying the LOAD DATA, and the regex, and inserting the result entries on my sql table, the result table should be:

```
1      08/e0/Breast_Cancer_Res_2001_Nov_2_3(1)_55-60.tar.gz     PMC13900
2      b0/ac/Breast_Cancer_Res_2001_Nov_9_3(1)_61-65.tar.gz     PMC13901
```

What should be the SQL command to do all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test with your two lines

```
create table mytest(
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
descr varchar(250),
code varchar(50)
) engine = myisam;

load data infile 'E:\file.txt'
into table mytest 
fields terminated by ';'
ignore 1 lines
(@descr,@code)
set descr = substring(@descr,1,locate('tar.gz',@descr)+5),
code = substring(@code,locate('PMC',@code))
```

Hope that it helps

Comment: @nick It's getting the file path ok, but not the PMCID. The result of the @code variable is: '3(1):55-60 PMC13900'

Comment: Very strange. Can you upload a sample file with some rows on http://www.myfreefilehosting.com/ ?

Comment: @nick http://myfreefilehosting.com/f/d10c218404_0.01MB   Please ignore the first line (I'm deleting it by hand. But, if able, add to sql code?)

Comment: Hi. I've added to the code the option to ignore first line. It seems to me that everything works fine. I've uploaded you the dump of my table after I've loaded it.  http://myfreefilehosting.com/uplFinished/3b77c268d5

Comment: @nick Thank you too much to answer. I'll ask my friend to retest, with your edit, and see if it help. Also, thank you to the dump database. I'll come back here with more details

Comment: @nick I followed your steps, and created a mysql schema myself here, and it's getting (for example for first line): "3(1):55-60 PMC13900" instead of just "PMC13900". I also tried on second line: substring_index(@code,'PMC',-3)   but with no success. Do you have any idea of what's going on?

Comment: @nick I could reproduce what I wanted using: 
"code = substring(@code,locate('PMC',@code))"   Could you update your code so that I can accept it as right answer?

Comment: @nick Thank you for all attention.